# Change the default Windows "graphics" in a C# program

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

http://i25.photobucket.com/albums/c51/dog199200/launchPanel.png

I am looking to find out how to do that in VS 2010 Pro, using C#..

I see application all the time that use their own graphics, but can not google, nor find any tuts on how anyone does this.

I would love any hints/ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Windows Presentation Foundation, at http://http://windowsclient.net/.  You can do stuff like the link you provided.  There are some good starter labs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742119.aspx

good luck :-)